# Typescript cannot find name of own class when importing Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript1.8

I'm attempting to use a node.js class (net in this instance) in a class I have defined.

Connection.ts:

```
import net = require('net');
class Connection  {

}
```

Then I reference my class in another file,

ConnectionContext.ts:

```
interface IConnectionContext {
    connection: Connection;
}
```

When I have this code, I see an underlined "Connection" in ConnectionContext that says `"IConnectionContext.ts(3,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Connection'"`

if I remove the import * as net from part, the compile error goes away.

I'm a bit confused, when I look at the resulting JavaScript, all my classes look identical in their creation. I'm not certain why typescript is saying the class doesn't exist.

Here's my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "bin/",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Based on this, what do I need to do to get my interface to see my class that uses node.js modules?

Comment: Not very familiar with typescript, but if it's using the es2015 module spec then it appears you're mixing the node-style modules with the new module syntax: `import net = require('net');`. Have you tried `import net from 'net';`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if I remove the import * as net from part, the compile error goes away.

In the absense of an `import` or `export` statement the file is considered *global*. As soon as you import / export it becomes a module and hence must be imported.

This is covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Comment: That's a bit annoying, having to import every external class I use.. I mean, not much different than how I did it with node.js originally, which makes sense. Still a bit annoying lol.

Comment: If you have a path typo you now get a compiler error. In js + node you probably ended up with a runtime error

Comment: Right, in order to get it to work in its current form, I have to do    import {Connection} from './Connection.ts';   which is kind of annoying but it makes sense from a pure node.js aspect.